# Can you explain why $x>\frac 23$ is not a solution to this inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

$|2x + 2| + |x - 1| > 3$

why can't $x>\frac 23$ be a part of the solution?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Suppose $x>2/3$, then if $x \ge 1 $, then $2x+2 + x -1 = 3x + 1 \ge 3 + 1 > 3$.
If $2/3 < x < 1$, then $2x+2 - x +1 = x + 3 > 3$. I don't see why it cannot be a solution. However, it is not a complete solution.

Comment: @Crostul.$|2 \cdot 1 + 2|+|1-1|=3$ ??

Comment: I appreciate all of the help so quickly! The 3 solutions are: x<-4/3, x>0, x>2/3. but the answers and wolfram say that the answer is the first 2 and not the 3rd!

Comment: @MilesGorman Wolfram sometimes gets things wrong. For example if you have an inequation with a few nested square roots, it won't restrict the possible values of $x$ with respect to all the roots.

Comment: I also just tried on inequality solver and they had the same answer... i doubt all 3 are wrong

Comment: Perhaps because the statement $x>\frac23$ is included in the statement $x>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the “highest common area” if you're solving simultaneous inequalities. If you split an inequality into cases, you have to take the *union* of the areas.

A solution of the problem can go like this: subdivide the real line in the intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $[-1,1]$ and $(1,\infty)$; they are so chosen because the expressions in the absolute values change sign at $-1$ and $1$ respectively.

Interval $(-\infty,-1)$: since $2x+2<0$ and $x-1<0$, the inequality becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
x<-1\\[4px]
-2x-2-x+1>3
\end{cases}
$$
that is, $x<-4/3$.

Interval $[-1,1]$: since $2x+2\ge0$ and $x-1<0$, the inequality becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
-1\le x\le 1\\[4px]
2x+2-x+1>3
\end{cases}
$$
that is, $0<x\le 1$.

Interval $(1,\infty)$: since $2x+2>0$ and $x-1>0$, the inequality becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
x>1\\[4px]
2x+2+x-1>3
\end{cases}
$$
that is, $x>1$.

> This is probably the case that's bothering you: the second inequality has indeed the solution set $x>2/3$, but we must match it with the previous condition that $x>1$.

Finally, we put together the solution sets:
$$
(-\infty,-4/3)\cup(0,1]\cup(1,\infty)=
(-\infty,-4/3)\cup(0,\infty)
$$
or, in other terms, the solutions are
$$
x<-\frac{4}{3}\quad\text{or}\quad x>0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x>2/3$, then if $x \ge 1 $, then $2x+2 + x -1 = 3x + 1 \ge 3 + 1 > 3$.
If $2/3 < x < 1$, then $2x+2 - x +1 = x + 3 > 3$.

This is, however, not a complete solution (probably why it is not a solution!?).
Consider $-1 \le x \le 2/3$, then $2x+2 - x +1 = x + 3 >3 $. This is only true if $x>0$.

If $x<-1$, then $-2x-2 - x +1 = -3x - 1 > 3.$ This holds if $x < -4/3$.

Thus the complete solution is $x \in (-\infty,-4/3) \cup (0,\infty)$.

Comment: $-\frac 43$ could be better than $-\frac 23$; $-3x-1>3 \implies -3x>4$  Edit your answer. Cheers.

Comment: i see that x> 2/3 and x>0 have common area, however I was taught you use the highest common area, maybe it is you take lowest... where am i going wrong???

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. Doing this right before going to sleep. :)

Comment: @MilesGorman Notice that if $x\ge1$ then it automatically satisfies the inequality. Therefore, what you want is to see if you can extend it. And that is why I assume if $-1 < x < 1$, this gives me the constraint that $x > 0$. And the similarly for the range of $x<-1$, which gives me the constraint that $x<-4/3$.